# Python: shift elements in a list with constant length

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for an elegant way to write a simple function that would shift the elements of list by a given number of positions, while keeping the list of the same length and padding empty positions with a default value. This would be the docstring of the function:

```
def shift_list(l, shift, empty=0):
    """
    Shifts the elements of a list **l** of **shift** positions,
    padding new items with **empty**::

        >>> l = [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0]
        >>> shift_list(l, 3)
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
        >>> shift_list(l, -3)
        [5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        >>> shift_list(l, -8)
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    """
    pass
```

How would you proceed ? Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: seems like adding empty to the start and poping is the way to go, keeping in mind shift is limited by len(l)

Comment: In place? Or a new copy?

Comment: why not use a deque? http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @Marcin: The docstring suggests that a new list is returned.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Not really. It just shows that a list is returned.

Comment: @Marcin: I said "suggests", not "proves".  The usual convention is that either the new value is returned (e.g. `str.replace()`) or the object is changed in place and `None` is returned (e.g. `list.sort()`).

Comment: @Marcin: You are right, I should have specified. Ideally, a new copy of the list created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use slice assignment:

```
def shift_list(l, shift, empty=0):
    src_index = max(-shift, 0)
    dst_index = max(shift, 0)
    length = max(len(l) - abs(shift), 0)
    new_l = [empty] * len(l)
    new_l[dst_index:dst_index + length] = l[src_index:src_index + length]
    return new_l
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a list, it has a few nice features that make it a natural choice for this problem. Working from the left of a deque is much less expensive than doing so on a list. Also it has a [maxlen argument](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque.maxlen) that can be used to make the code prettier and faster. I'm rather sure using `itertools.repeat` instead of `[empty] * n` is more efficient, both memory-wize and with regards to speed.

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import repeat

def shift_list(l, n, empty=0):
    d = deque(l, maxlen=len(l))
    if n > 0:
        d.extendleft(repeat(empty, min(n, len(l))))
    elif n < 0:
        d.extend(repeat(empty, min(-n, len(l))))
    # return list(d) to pass your doctest, at the cost of performance
    return d
```

A bit of a warning though -- while the time complexity of iterating over the elements of a deque is comparable to doing the same on a list, item lookup *may* be rather expensive -- it depends on the index: `s[0]` and `s[-1]` is very fast, `s[len(s)/2]` is the most expensive. So if you do a lot of lookups, consider either using another solution, or converting the result back to a list. See [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for an overview.

Answer (score 1):

A bit naïve, but job's done.

```
def shift(l, shift, empty=0):
    reverse = False
    if shift < 0:
        reverse = True
        shift = abs(shift)
    while (shift > 0) :
        if reverse:
            l.pop(0)
            l.append(empty)
        else:
            l.pop()
            l.insert(0, empty)
        shift-=1



l = [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0]
shift(l, 3)
print l
l = [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0]
shift(l, -3)
print l
l = [0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 0]
shift(l, -8)
print l
```

Comment: It works, but the doctest given wouldn't pass since the list is modified in place.

Comment: This solution suffers from the same performance problems as Aram's solution, it has [O(len(l)*shift)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) time complexity. Both `l.pop(0)` and `l.insert(0, empty)` are [very expensive operations](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 1):

A non intuitive way of rotating a list

```
def shift_list(l, shift, empty=0):
    l1=[empty]*len(l)+l+[empty]*len(l)
    l1=l1[len(l)-shift:][0:len(l)]
    return l1+[empty]*(len(l)-len(l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it?

```
def shift_list(l, shift, empty=0):
    while shift > 0:
        l.insert(0,empty)
        l.pop()
        shift -= 1
    ​return l
```

Comment: It would, but it is `O(len(l)*shift)`, which is rather suboptimal.  (And also get rid of those braces, semicolons and redundant parens. `shift--` isn't Python either.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
def shift_list(l, shift, empty=0):
    if shift > 0:
        return [empty] * shift + l[:-shift]

    return l[-shift:] + [empty] * abs(shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method does not answer the question, but I still find it helpful for those who would like to shift the valuse like a circle.

```
# Shift to the left.
shift = 1
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = a[shift:] + a[:shift]
# [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

or

```
# Shift to the right.
shift = -1
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = a[shift:] + a[:shift]
# [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The author of the question wanted a little bit different behavior, he wanted to fill the the left or right side with zeros, it's like shifting bits in C/C++. While my shift works like a linked list that is linked like a circle where the end node is connected to the start node.

Comment: Then you should have posted it as an answer to this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, you are right, It would be better if I posted it there, I just didn't find the right question instantly, but thanks to your link, now it would be easier for any to find the other solutions. They are related any way.