# Python array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays

I have array `[1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2]`

I want to loop it x times, each times moving array every element 1 position forward:

So next loop will be:

2.`[2,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,1]`

3.
`[1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2,1,2]`

etc....

How can I manipulate array like this way?

**EDIT:**

What I thought, but maybe some better tricks:

Just go over the array with while loop and create new array with for cycle.

```
for i in range(11)
    array[i] = array[i-1]
```

**etc etc..its pseudo code**

Comment: sounds like HW? You have to try to learn! :)

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry no I just develop all stuff, look my other questions, I am just like to learn new stuff.

Comment: Your loop won't work, because by the time you try to give a[1] the value of a[0], the old value of a[0] has already been overwritten with the value of a[-1], so you wind up with the whole array being copies of the last element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to shift a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a List data structure isn't an efficient way to do this. A **Queue** would be more appropriate. In any case:

**Using a Queue**

As I suggested, using a Queue ([collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque)):

```
>>> q = collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> for _ in xrange(5):
...     q.rotate(-1)
... 
>>> q
deque([6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

**Keeping the List**

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> for _ in xrange(5):
...     a = a[1:] + a[:1]
... 
>>> a
[6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively (faster than the previous one):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> for _ in xrange(5):
...     a.append(a.pop(0))
... 
>>> a
[6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here you can change xrange for whatever you want to iterate over.

Timeit analysis:

**Pop-Append**

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a.append(a.pop(0))', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]', number=1000000)
0.24548697471618652
>>> timeit.timeit('a.append(a.pop(0))', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]', number=100000000)
23.65538215637207
```

**Slicing**

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a=a[1:] + a[:1]', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]', number=1000000)
0.36037278175354004
>>> timeit.timeit('a=a[1:] + a[:1]', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]', number=100000000)
35.06173801422119
```

**Queue**

```
>>> timeit.timeit('q.rotate(-1)', setup='import collections; q = collections.deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])', number=1000000)
0.16829514503479004
>>> timeit.timeit('q.rotate(-1)', setup='import collections; q = collections.deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])', number=100000000)
16.012277841567993
```

With a little optimization, basically removing the __getattr__ call for append, pop and rotate:

**Pop-Append**

```
>>> timeit.timeit('aa(ap(0))', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; aa=a.append; ap=a.pop', number=1000000)
0.15255093574523926
>>> timeit.timeit('aa(ap(0))', setup='a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; aa=a.append; ap=a.pop', number=100000000)
14.50795292854309
```

**Queue**

```
>>> timeit.timeit('r(-1)', setup='import collections; q = collections.deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); r=q.rotate', number=1000000)
0.13374090194702148
>>> timeit.timeit('r(-1)', setup='import collections; q = collections.deque([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]); r=q.rotate', number=100000000)
11.435136079788208
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) because it has the built in method rotate:

```
import collections

d = collections.deque([1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2])
for _ in xrange(number_of_shifts):
    d.rotate(-1)
    print list(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,1,2]
for i in range(10):
    my_list.insert(0,my_list.pop())
    print my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You question finds its answer in this question (which answers help in improving ...)
[Efficient way to shift a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

To make it short, make a function to shift your array:

```
def shift(l, n):
   return l[n:] + l[:n]
```

Then call this function in a loop:

```
myarray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for ii in range(10):
   myarray=shift(myarray, 1)
   print myarray
```

Comment: This is also quite inefficient.  Three new lists created for each shift!

Comment: Sure. But it answers the question (that was not about optimization). I though it would have some educational value for a beginner.