# clean way to accomplish -- if x in [(0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0)]:?

Tags: python

If not, then a canonical name for a function? 'Cycle' makes sense to me, but that's taken.

The example in the header is written for clarity and brevity. Real cases I'm working with have a lot of repetition.
(e.g., I want [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1] to "match" [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0])

This type of thing is obscuring my algorithm and filling my code with otherwise useless repetition.

Comment: Do you want to match any permutation of 0,1,2 or only certain ones? E.g. in your example you don't have [1,0,2], [0,2,1] etc

Comment: Not permutations. Just a circular list.

Comment: The optimal solution for this is probably dynamic programming, but that may be overcomplicated if the simple solution is fast enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the cycles of the list with:

```
def cycles(a):
    return [ a[i:] + a[:i] for i in range(len(a)) ]
```

You can then check if b is a cycle of a with:

```
b in cycles(a)
```

If the length of the list is long, or if want to make multiple comparison to the same cycles, it may be beneficial (performance wise) to embed the results in a set.

```
set_cycles = set(cycles(a))
b in set_cycles
```

You can prevent necessarily constructing all the cycles by embedding the equality check in the list and using any:

```
any( b == a[i:]+a[:i] for i in range(len(a)))
```

You could also achieve this effect by turning the `cycles` function into a generator.

Comment: You could probably do better if you stored your cycles as tuples which you could pack into a `set`.  As long as the `cycles` are small enough to reasonably store them all at once, I don't see any reason to not use a set...

Comment: @mgilson. Nice. But the asker seemed after the general function.

Comment: Or, you could do `any( b == a[i:]+a[:i] for i in range(len(a)))` which gets you short-circuiting :)

Comment: Think I'll go with a generator. That'll make it easier to guess how I'm using it when I see the function by itself. Don't think I've used a generator with 'in' or 'any' before, but that part should be easy to guess. Now for a name: ouroboros maybe? ha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Misunderstood your question earlier. If you want to check if any cycle of a list `l1` matches a list `l2` the best (cleanest/most pythonic) method is probably `any(l1 == l2[i:] + l2[:i] for i in xrange(len(l2)))`. There is also a `rotate` method in [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) that you might find useful.

Comment: This return a false positive for [1,2,3,4], [2,4,1,3]

Comment: Misunderstood the question - deleting

Comment: `deque.rotate` will outperform list slicing by a pretty good margin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cycle` from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), together with `islice` to cut it up. This basically puts [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13124747/1404505) in a list comprehension so the list is shifted once for every element.

```
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle
>>> l = [0,1,2]
>>> [tuple(islice(cycle(t),i,i+len(t))) for i,_ in enumerate(l)]
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1)]
```