# Removing the line from file once processed

Tags: python, file

I am reading content from file line by line. Once line processed, I clear it out. Here is the code

```
import os
lines = open('q0.txt').readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines[:]):
    print line
    flag = raw_input()
    print lines[i]
    del lines[i]

open('q0.txt', 'w').writelines(lines)
```

I am going through large q0.txt. My intension is, if there is any intruption in between, I should not reprocess previously processed lines again.

In above code, though I delete `lines[i]`, it still remain in file. What is wrong?

Comment: You are deleting a line from your list, not a file. Also i think you cant delete lines from a file dynamically. You need to create new one containing all lines of interest.

Comment: Is that indentation right? I'm asking because `raw_input` will wait until a user inputs something. You should never see the second `print lines[i]`, much less reaching the `writelines` in the end of your code unless you keep pressing `Enter` on your keyboard.

Comment: @BorrjaX: there was indentation issue while pasting code here. corrected

Comment: Nopes, still happening... :-)

Comment: @BorrajaX: yeah correct, 2nd `print line[]` does not get printed. But as first `print line` works it will not cause any issue for me.

Comment: It does, since it's gonna block your whole program...

Comment: @BorrajaX: yes, there index out of boudn ossue to as sriram explained. any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `raw_input` is blocking your code, you might wanna separate the process in two [threads](http://www.python-course.eu/threads.php): the `main` one and one that you create in your code. Since threads run concurrently and in an unpredictable order (kinda), you're not gonna be able to control *exactly* on what line the interruption is gonna reach your main `while` loop). Threads are a very tricky part to get right and it requires a *lot* of reading, testing and checking why things happen the way they happen...

Also, since you don't mind consuming your lines, you can do what's called a *destructive* read: Load the contents of the file into a `lines` variable, and keep getting the last one with `pop()` until you run out of lines to consume (or the flag has been activated). Check what a [pop()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method does in a list. Be aware that `pop()` always returns **the last** item of a list. If you want the items printed in the original order, you have to use [shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python) or `pop` from a previously [reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python) list.

```
import threading

interrupt=None

def flag_activator():
    global interrupt
    interrupt = raw_input("(!!) Type yes when you wanna stop\n\n")
    print "Oh gosh! The user input %s" % interrupt

th = threading.Thread(target=flag_activator)
th.start()


fr = open('q0.txt', 'r')
lines = fr.readlines()
fr.close()

while lines and interrupt != 'yes':
    print "I read this line: %s" % lines.pop()

if len(lines) > 0:
    print "Crap! There are still lines"
    fw = open('q0.txt', 'w')
    fw.writelines(lines)
    fw.close()
```

Now, that code is gonna block your terminal until you type `yes` on the terminal.

PS: Don't forget to close your opened files (if you don't want to call `close()` explicitly, see the `with` statement [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

### EDIT (as per OP's comments to my misunderstanding):

If what you want is to ensure that the file will not contain the already processed line if your script suddenly stops, an inefficient (but straightforward) way to accomplish that is:

1. Open the file for read and write (you're gonna need a different file descriptor for each operation)
2. Load all the file's lines into a variable
3. Process the first line
4. Remove that line from the list variable
5. Write the remaining list to the file
6. Repeat until no more *lines* are loaded.

All this opening/closing of files is really, really inefficient, though, but here it goes:

```
done = False
while done == False:
    with open("q0.txt", 'r') as fr, open("q0.txt", 'w') as fw:
        lines = fr.readlines()
        if len(lines) > 0:
            print lines[0] # This would be your processing
            del lines[0]
            fw.writelines(lines)
        else:
            done = True
```

Comment: dude thanks for your efforts, but it behave away from what I want

Comment: I put raw_input just to check whether my program deleted the line inbetween or not

Comment: LoL... I imagined **:-D** But meh... Theads are something worth knowing about.

Comment: @puncrazy: The `pop` (or `shift`) parts can still be useful, though... You won't have the `IndexError` with them.

Comment: Ok! This got personal!! **:-D** (I was curious, myself)... I've edited the answer. I think it should fit your question better?

Answer (score 2):

I expect the above code to throw an `IndexError` somewhere.

Why? Let us say your script reads a 100 line file. `lines[:]` will have 100 lines in it.
Meanwhile, `del lines[i]` will continue deleting items.

Eventually, the for loop will reach 100th element. If there is, even one single `del` operation, `del lines[99]` will fail and throw an IndexError.

Therefore, the lines `open('q0.txt', 'w').writelines(lines)` will never get executed when there is a deleted. And, hence, the file continue to remain the same.

This is my understanding.