# rotate elements in a list by a one position to the left

Tags: list, python-3.x, rotation

I'm asked to write a function `rotate_left3(nums)` that takes a `list` of ints of **length 3** called `nums` and returns a `list` with the elements "rotated left" so [1, 2, 3] yields [2, 3, 1].

The questions asks to rotate lists of length 3 **only**. I can easily do this by the following function (as long as the lists will only be of length 3):

```
def  rotate_left3(nums):
    return [nums[1]] + [nums[2]] + [nums[0]]
```

However, my question is, how do I do the same operation but with lists of unknown lengths?

*I have seen some solutions that are complicated to me as a beginner. so I'd appreciate if we can keep the solution as simple as possible.*

Comment: I think it's *no duplicate* because it asks for rotating by exactly one. This is a special case with special properties, for example concerning performance, that deserves its own answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a list:

```
>>> nums = range(5)
```

Now, let's rotate left by one position:

```
>>> nums[1:] + nums[:1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

If we wanted to rotate left by two positions, we would use:

```
>>> nums[2:] + nums[:2]
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```