# Using Python To Change The Order Of A List

Tags: python

I am new to Python..

I have a list **(names.txt)** which is four names:

- Colin
- Gary
- Gibby
- Ross

I would like to output the list from the file, then change the order of the names by one space and save that output at the original **"names.txt"** file.

i.e.

> Run1 would be:  Colin Gary Gibby Ross
>
> Run2 would be: Gary Gibby Ross Colin
>
> Run3 would be: Gibby Ross Colin Gary

....and so on.

The code I have so far is able to take the file and output as a list, but I don't know how to move the order by 1 place and save again:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Open a file
with open ('names.txt', 'r') as f:
  list1 = f.read().splitlines()
  for item1 in list1[0:4]:
   print (item1)
f.close()
```

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `mylist = mylist[1:]+mylist[:1]`

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python) answer details how to shift a list using `collections.deque` which they state is optimised for "pushing and pulling on both ends" To that end, I have included the example code below for your convenience.

```
from collections import deque
items = deque([1, 2])
items.append(3) # deque == [1, 2, 3]
items.rotate(1) # The deque is now: [3, 1, 2]
items.rotate(-1) # Returns deque to original state: [1, 2, 3]
item = items.popleft() # deque == [2, 3]
```

Comment: @shravster You mean the answer I linked to my post?

Comment: No worries, just didn't want any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just print all starting from index `1` in a loop. At the end print index `0`

```
for i in range(1:len(list1)):
    print(list1[i])
print(list1[0])
```

Or if you need to have it in a new list:

```
list1 = list1[1:] + list1[:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate a sequence like this, using slice notation.

```
def rotate(sequence, shift=1):
    return sequence[-shift:] + sequence[:-shift]

>>> rotate([1, 2, 3, 4])
[4, 1, 2, 3]

>>> rotate('hello world', 5)
'o worldhell'

>>> rotate(['Colin', 'Gary', 'Gibby', 'Ross'], -1)
['Gary', 'Gibby', 'Ross', 'Colin']
```

This `rotate` function does not mutate the original sequence. For very long sequences and faster performance, you can check out `collections.deque` from the standard library. The `deque` sequence type can be rotated in-place in a memory and performance efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

This reads your existing `names.txt` file in and displays the contents. It then changes the order by 1 and writes the resulting list back to the same file:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    list1 = f.read().splitlines()
    print('\n'.join(list1))
    list1 = list1[1:] + list1[:1]

with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(list1))
```

Run1

```
Colin
Gary
Gibby
Ross
```

Run2

```
Gary
Gibby
Ross
Colin
```