# Order list number from given number

Tags: python, sorting

In detail, ex: I have a list weekday:

```
list_week_day = [0,2,4,5,6]
```

if **today.weekday() = 3** , then order **list_week_day = [4,5,6,0,2]**

So, how to do that ???

Comment: Does this only have to solve this specific problem or are you going to use repurpose this algorithm?

Answer (score 6):

```
new = old[n:] + old[:n]
```

You append the front part of the list to the back part.  Can you finish after that hint?  **n** is your weekday.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following? I suspect it is not the most efficient way to get what you desire, but it certainly is a way to get it.

```
list_week_day[today.weekday() : ] + list_week_day[ : today.weekday()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also try:

```
wday = 3
[(x + wday) % 7 for x in list_week_day]

# [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python), you can use numpy's roll command, choosing a suitable value to roll by:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.arange(1,10) #Generate some data
>>> numpy.roll(a,1)
array([9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> numpy.roll(a,-1)
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1])
>>> numpy.roll(a,5)
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> numpy.roll(a,9)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: numpy's a pretty heavy dependency for something that can be done with vanilla lists...

Comment: @nrlakin: It's a good point. Though I think the clarity of the syntax is a definite plus, so it's worth thinking about if you'll be using numpy anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the key. If it's running on a machine with an existing numpy installation, it's a nice solution.