# Error shuffling list into new list

Tags: python

I am creating a list by shifting an old list **out_g**, item by item, and appending the result to the new one, **new_sets**. As I am iterating, I check the resulting shift, and it is correct. After this is complete, I print out the new list, and it is all a single object repeated. What am I missing?

The error occurs during the **for** loop at the end, where I append the results to **new_sets**.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

def LFSR(register, feedback, output):
    """
    https://natronics.github.io/blag/2014/gps-prn/
    :param list feedback: which positions to use as feedback (1 indexed)
    :param list output: which positions are output (1 indexed)
    :returns output of shift register:

    """

    # calculate output
    out = [register[i-1] for i in output]
    if len(out) > 1:
        out = sum(out) % 2
    else:
        out = out[0]

    # modulo 2 add feedback
    fb = sum([register[i-1] for i in feedback]) % 2

    # shift to the right
    for i in reversed(range(len(register[1:]))):
        register[i+1] = register[i]

    # put feedback in position 1
    register[0] = fb

    return out

def shiftInPlace(l, n):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python
    n = n % len(l)
    head = l[:n]
    l[:n] = []
    l.extend(head)
    return l

##########
## Main ##
##########
n = 3
# init register states
if n == 5 :
    LFSR_A = [1,1,1,1,0]
    LFSR_B = [1,1,1,0,1]
    LFSR_A_TAPS =[5,4,3,2]
    LFSR_B_TAPS =[5,3]
elif n == 7:
    LFSR_A = [1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
    LFSR_B = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
    LFSR_A_TAPS = [7,3,2,1]
    LFSR_B_TAPS = [7,3]
elif n == 3:
    LFSR_A = [1,0,1]
    LFSR_B = [0,1,1]
    LFSR_A_TAPS = [3,2]
    LFSR_B_TAPS = [3,1]

output_reg = [n]
N = 2**n-1
out_g = []
for i in range(0,N): #replace N w/ spread_fact
    a = (LFSR(LFSR_A, LFSR_A_TAPS, output_reg))
    b = (LFSR(LFSR_B, LFSR_B_TAPS, output_reg))
    out_g.append(a ^ b)

# FOR BALANCED GOLD CODES NUMBER OF ONES MUST BE ONE MORE THAN NUMBER
# OF ZEROS 
nzeros = sum(x == 0 for x in out_g)
nones  = sum(x == 1 for x in out_g)
print "Gold Code Output Period[%d] of length %d -- {%d} 0's, {%d} 1's" % (N,N,nzeros,nones)

# produce all time shifted versions of the code
new_sets = []
for i in range(0,N-1):
    new_sets.append(shiftInPlace(out_g,1))
    # a=shiftInPlace(out_g,1)
    # new_sets.append(a)
    print new_sets[i]

print new_sets
```

**My output :**

```
Gold Code Output Period[7] of length 7 -- {3} 0's, {4} 1's
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Correct values are printing on the iteration, but the final list has all the same values.

Comment: Because you are *appending the same list to your accumulator*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem should be obvious from your output - you are seeing the same list *because you are appending the same list*. Consider - you even *name* your function "shift in place", so that returns a mutated version of the same list you passed in, and then you *append that same list*. So one quick fix is to make a copy which you end up appending:

```
new_sets = []
for i in range(0,N-1):
    new_sets.append(shiftInPlace(out_g,1)[:]) # append copy
    # a=shiftInPlace(out_g,1)
    # new_sets.append(a)
    print new_sets[i]
```

This gives the output:

```
Gold Code Output Period[7] of length 7 -- {3} 0's, {4} 1's
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

As an aside, for efficient in-place rotations, consider changing your data-structure to a `collections.deque`, which implements a doubly-linked list:

```
In [10]: from collections import deque
    ...: d = deque([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
    ...: print(d)
    ...: for i in range(0, N-1):
    ...:     d.rotate(-1)
    ...:     print(d)
    ...:
deque([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
deque([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
deque([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
deque([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
deque([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
deque([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
deque([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: @gutelfuldead make sure you check out the edit that suggests using `collections.deque` instead of `list`

Comment: In case that's not clear ... When you append in this fashion, you append a *reference* to the in-place list.  Your two-line code with variable **a** works the same way.  You've appended 6 copies of the same variable reference; every time you shift the list, you shift the underlying object.  All of the appended references point to that object.

Comment: @Prune variable *a*? Sorry, I am not sure what you are trying to say...

Comment: I used the code he commented out for more detailed tracing.  See the answer I posted ... once he (correctly) accepted yours.

Comment: @Prune aha! I totally ignored the commented out code :)

Comment: Thank you both. I see the error I was making and understand the cause now.

Comment: Congratulations -- your mental parser is working in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

You might try creating your list of rotations like this:

```
>>> li=[1,0,1,1,0,0]
>>> [li[r:]+li[:r] for r in range(len(li))]
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

... following up on my comment to `juanpa`'s answer ...

When you append in this fashion, you append a reference to the in-place list. Your two-line code with variable a works the same way. You've appended 6 copies of the same variable reference; every time you shift the list, you shift the underlying object. All of the appended references point to that object.

Here's detailed output tracing your program.  Note how *all* of the elements of **new_sets** change on every iteration.  In my repair, I used the two-line assignment, but added a copy like this: `new_sets.append(a[:])`

```
Gold Code Output Period[7] of length 7 -- {3} 0's, {4} 1's
TRACE out_g = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [0]   l= [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
TRACE a= [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  new_sets= [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]] 

TRACE out_g = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [1]   l= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
TRACE a= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]  new_sets= [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]] 

TRACE out_g = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [1]   l= [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
TRACE a= [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]  new_sets= [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]] 

TRACE out_g = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [0]   l= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
TRACE a= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  new_sets= [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]] 

TRACE out_g = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [1]   l= [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
TRACE a= [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]  new_sets= [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]] 

TRACE out_g = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
ENTER shiftInPlace, l= [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
LEAVE shiftInPlace, head= [0]   l= [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
TRACE a= [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]  new_sets= [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]] 

[[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```