# How can I each one element of the list in the infinity loop

Tags: python, list

I have an infinity loop, where I send some request, and I wanna send an element of list from the first to the last and over and over again.
Example:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
while True:
    myfunc(my_list)
    '''
    first iterate: 'a',
    second iterate: 'b', third iterate: 'c',
    fourth iterate: 'a', and so on.
    '''
```

Comment: Use the % operator

Comment: You could shift/rotate the list and always use the first element. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python

Comment: Aren't you looking for itertools.cycle?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.cycle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for element in cycle(my_list):
    print(element)

# output: a b c a b c a b c ...
```

Comment: How can I use it in an infinity loop?
Something like:

`while True:
send_request(list)`

Comment: @JoeDoe This _is_ an infinite loop. I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: I start an infinity loop, where I get some news, and comment that article with each one element (from the first to the last)

Comment: `cycle(my_list)` is an infinite source of values; you don't necessarily need an infinite *loop* to use it. Let `x = cycle(my_list)`. Each time you call `next(x)`, you'll get a value: `a`, then `b`, then `c`, then `a`, then `b`, etc.

Comment: @JoeDoe Ok? I really can't see the problem. Which part of my code is preventing you from doing all of that? If you have any additional requirements that my code doesn't fulfill, please explain those requirements in detail - and not in the comments here, but in your question.

Comment: `x = cycle(my_list); while True: next_item = next(x); ...`.

Comment: I'll try to use this

Comment: Yes that's the exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thank you very much