# Shift array to make first and last columns adjacent

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, transform, gdal

I'm struggling how to explain this in the question title so I'll try better here.

I have an array which contains 360 columns and 180 rows which represents each degree of latitude and longitude on earth. For clarity, my data looks like the following:

```
longitudes = [0, 1, 2 ... 358, 359]
latitudes = [90, -89 ... -89, -90]
data = np.random.randint(5, (180, 360))
```

It looks like [this](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/on388/grids/grid003.gif), where longitude '0' is equal to 0E and '359' is equal to -1E.

As you can see, Africa is split at the start and end of the array and I would like to shift the array so that the first columns corresponds to -180E and the last columns corresponds to 180E, like the traditional world view ([map](http://www.satsig.net/lat_long.htm)) - this will make subsetting the array to 'cookie cut' Africa out.

How do I shift/transform my array so that the first and last column are adjacent?

(Extra: since you can think of my array as a cylinder, as geographically, the first and last rows are adjacent, but how do I change where the 'cylinder is cut' - the analogy I've been thinking of)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to shift a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Comment: I've looked at the possible dupe and don't see this as a solution. I understand that it would work for my two lists, but not for my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `numpy.roll()`.

I firstly found the index of the column corresponding to 180E using:

```
idx = (longitude.index(180))
```

Then, I 'rolled' the data based on this index to move 180E to the furthest left column using:

```
rolled_data = np.roll(data, idx, axis=1)
```

This successfully centred the 0E column to create my desired output.

Answer (score -1):

please see this answer: [Efficient way to shift a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Seems to do the same as you want.

From the accepted answer:

[Collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects)

```
from collections import deque
items = deque([1, 2])
items.append(3) # deque == [1, 2, 3]
items.rotate(1) # The deque is now: [3, 1, 2]
items.rotate(-1) # Returns deque to original state: [1, 2, 3]
item = items.popleft() # deque == [2, 3]
```