# ABC ----> ABC, CAB, BCA only order matters but not truly a itertools permutation

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to write a simple Python script capable of the following:

The user inputs a string of letters and the code returns the combinations in the following way:

```
ABC ----> ABC, CAB, BCA.
```

In this instance the "neighbors" remain the same but the last letter is moved to the beginning. I've been trying `itertools` but `combinations` and `permutations` aren't exactly what I'm looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `s = s[-1]+s[:-1]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for *rotations*, not permutations.

[`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque) can do that.

```
>>> d = deque('ABC')
>>> ''.join(d)
>>> 'ABC'
>>> d.rotate(1)
>>> ''.join(d)
>>> 'CAB'
>>> d.rotate(1)
>>> ''.join(d)
>>> 'BCA'
```

If you want to store all the rotations in a list, you can do

```
>>> d = deque('ABC')
>>> result = [''.join(d)]
>>> for _ in range(len(d) - 1):
...:    d.rotate(1)
...:    result.append(''.join(d))
...:    
>>> result
>>> ['ABC', 'CAB', 'BCA']
```

You should be able to handle the user input stuff yourself.

Comment: See also [Efficient way to shift a list in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new at Python and appreciate your input and help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't thing there is a direct function for it, but it's fairly simple to generate a oneliner

```
x='abcde'
result = [x[-i:]+x[:-i] for i in range(len(x))]
# result will be ['abcde', 'eabcd', 'deabc', 'cdeab', 'bcdea']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: This worked well for regular string as asked in this question. I have a new issue is that the string is now separated by "," where I want to split them. What I want to do is: A,B,C ---------> 'A,B,C'    'C,A,B'    'B,C,A'

Comment: The oneliner works with any iterable, so the easiest for you is to split the string with the separator you want.

    x='a,b,c,d,e'.split(',')