# Find the original string given the output of a string after 15 rotations

Tags: string, rotation

You have rotated a string 15 times to produce the output: ' Gdipit bt 15 ixbth! '. What was the original string before rotation?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Please check [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use ROT13 and put the -15 amount to get the answer for Gdipit bt 15 ixbth! and your asnwer should get

Rotate me 15 times!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like homework indeed ;)

Look here to read something about rotation:
[Efficient way to shift a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)