# Determine if two arrays are a rotated version of each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Similar question has been asked in JAVA, but can someone help me in improving the code: And explain what would be the time complexity and space complexity of my code. My code checks if two arrays are rotated version of each other:

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

list2b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]

is_rotation(list1, list2b) should return True.

list2c = [4, 5, 6, 9, 1, 2, 3]

is_rotation(list1, list2c) should return False.

My code:

```
def is_rotation (list1,list2):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    result = True

    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False  

    while i < len(list1) -1 and j < len(list1) -1:

        if list1[i] == list2[j]:
            i = i +1
            j = j +1
            break
        elif list1[i] > list2[j]:
            j = j +1
        else:
            i = i +1
    else:
        return False

    for l in range(i,len(list1)):

        if i == j:
            if list1[i] != list2[j]: 
                return False
        elif list1[i] != list2[j] or list2[i] != list1[k]:
            return False
        else:
            i = i +1
            j = j +1
            k = k +1

    return result
```

Comment: Some comments to describe what task the loops are suppose to accomplish would help

Comment: *If the values are unique*, consider this simplification: i2 = index of l1[0] in l2; rotated iff, for x in 0 up to len l1, where l1[x] == l2[(i2 + x) % len l1] - that can be written in two simple loops (or less). That is, with a unique set of values, it’s just comparing sequence equality given a “bias” for the second list start that was previously selected.

Comment: The above can be modified to work with non-unique values by trying all occurrences of l1[0] in l2 as the “bias” until one matches.

Comment: A fast way to do this, O(n), would be to use some fast algorithm for exact string matching, like Knuth-Morris-Pratt, but applied to list items instead of letters.

Comment: An easy way to do it is to just look at all possible rotations. A rotation of list `a` by `k` positions is simply `a[k:] + a[:k]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

A bit hacky way:

```py
def is_rotation(lst1, lst2):
    if(len(lst1)==len(lst2)):
        return (str(lst1)[1:-1] in str(lst2+lst2)) & (str(lst2)[1:-1] in str(lst1+lst1)) 
    else:
        return False
```

How does it work:

(1) check if both lists are of the same length, if not return `False`

(2) if they do, convert first list to `string`, drop the most outer brackets (by dropping first and last character- you can do any brackets there, not only square ones, it can be a `tuple` too).

(3) `lst2+lst2` will return all the elements of `lst2` duplicated in sequence (so one `lst2` after another). Then converted to string it will just return its string format of `list`

(4) as per the comments- in order to handle the corner cases - we should check both ways, since if `lst1` is rotated version of `lst2` then `lst2` is the rotated version of `lst1`

**Tests**

```py
print(is_rotation([561, 1, 1, 1, 135], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
#outputs False
print(is_rotation([[1,2,3,4], 2, 3, 4], [1, 2,3,4]))
#outputs False
print(is_rotation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]))
#outputs True
```

Comment: Not exactly: for example, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] will incorrectly be seen as a rotation of [54321, 1, 1, 1, 12345].

Comment: @Amadan Why is it the best way to do this?

Comment: Definitely not the best way: fails for some patterns of values (as @Gassa pointed out), requires costly transformations to strings and more extra memory than even copying the whole lists would require.

Comment: Thanks guys- please have a look now - this should do the trick for the cases you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I though in another way to do this:

```
def is_rotation (list1,list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i:] + list1[:i] == list2:
            return True

    return False
```

1) Test if both have same length.

2) The loop will just rotate the list all the possibilities and check if in one of them both are equal..

I don't know if this is the best way, but is simple to understand ;)

Comment: Is testing that the list elements are ints part of the task?

Comment: Probably not.. I will edit this removing the testing part.

Answer (score 0):

For a somewhat more explicit approach, you can generate all the rotations of a given list using itertools, one by one, with this:

```
import itertools as it
def get_rotations(lst1):
    foo = it.cycle(lst1)
    for y in range(len(lst1)):
        result = []
        for x in range(len(lst1)):
            result.append(next(foo))
        yield result
        next foo
```

Then you can do:

```
def is_rotated(L1, L2) -> bool:
    bar = get_rotations(L1)
    While True:
        try:
            if next(bar) == L2;
                return True
        except StopIteration:
                return False
```

Aside: I think this breaks all the traditional views on using exceptions to control the normal flow of program logic, however... It feels wrong, somehow (background in C++, where we were repeatedly told to never do this kind of thing.). Is it Pythonic?

Comment: Instead of the try-except, you could simply iterate over `far`, and use an else statement in place of the except to return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cycle from itertools to optimize the number of comparisons and avoid creating additional copies of the data. (i.e. O(1) space in O(n) time)

Here's an example of a function that will return the rotation offset if the two lists are a rotation of each other or None if they do not match.  The logic will never need more than 2N comparisons to determine the offset.

```
from itertools import cycle
def getRotation(listA,listB):
    if len(listA) != len(listB): return None
    unmatched,offset = len(listA),0
    iterA,iterB      = cycle(listA),cycle(listB)
    a = next(iterA)
    while unmatched and offset<len(listA):
        b = next(iterB)
        if a==b:
            unmatched -= 1
            a = next(iterA)
        else:
            unmatched = len(listA)
            offset   += 1
    if unmatched: return None
    return offset
```

outpu:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
print(getRotation(list1,list2b)) # 4 (rotation to the right)
```

You can adapt it to simply return True or False if needed.

It can also be easily adapted to check if a list can be produced by cycling over the other. (e.g.  [2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2] can be produced by cycling [1,2,3]). *I did not include that feature in the example to avoid confusing the issue.*