# How do we make an element in a list go backwards multiple times in python?

Tags: python

here is the code I'm working with but it keeps moving the element backwards once not multiple times

```
def backwards(input_list):
    total = 0
    while total < 3:
        total +=1
        return input_list[1:] + input_list[:1]

example : a = from ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] to ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'] but multiple times
```

Comment: you `return` that immidiatly leave the loop and the function

Comment: `Multiple times` , how many times exactly. Your loop does that for 3 times as you have while condition `total<3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you return on the first iteration of the loop so it runs only once. you can fix it like this:

```
def backwards(input_list):
    total = 0
    while total < 3:
        total +=1
        input_list = input_list[1:] + input_list[:1]
    return input_list
```

but we can improve that:

```
def backwards(input_list):
    total = 0
    while total < 3:
        total +=1
        input_list.append(input_list.pop(0))
    return input_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.roll()` for this. For example:

```
np.roll(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], -1).tolist()
```

will return:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

Comment: how do you use np.roll() ?

Comment: It basically rolls your list/array to left (if shift is negative) or to right (if shift is positive).

Comment: Its a function from the module [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). So for this example to work you would have to add `import numpy as np`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but you might like:

```
a[::-1]
```

Which would return your list, but "backwards" using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question - don't answer! Comment and ask for clarifications instead. Anyway, this is not at all related to the question. OP is trying to make a cyclic shift of the list, not reverse it