# How is this getting first value same from 2nd repeat?

Tags: arrays, list

```
def solution(A):
    A_inp = A
    roated_a =list(range(len(A_inp)))
    
    k=1
    while k < 3:
        for i in range(len(A_inp)-1):
            
            roated_a[i+1] = A_inp[i]
            roated_a[0] = A_inp[len(A_inp)-1]
            
        A_inp = roated_a
        k+=1
        print(roated_a)
        

inp_arr = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the list items : ").split()]
solution(inp_arr)
```

This code should rotate the input array.
Input given : 3 6 8 7
Expected Output should be : 7 3 6 8 ; 8 7 3 6; 6 8 7 3
But I am getting : 7 3 6 8 ; 7 7 7 7 ; 7 7 7 7

How is it getting the 7 for all the index after first iteration ?
Where is the error ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Comment: No, I need to know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Can you `elaborate` the function's requirements? (how it supposed to work)  We can `guess` but rather not...

Comment: The code won't work as intended in Python 2. You can't use Python 2's `input()` function like that. It would have to be `raw_input()`. Please remove the [python-2.7] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A_inp = roated_a` makes both variable names to refer the same object. So, when you update `roated_a`, you also change `A_inp`, starting 2nd iteration.

The fix (if you decide to stick with this implementation) is to make an actual copy:

```
A_inp = roated_a.copy()
```

Comment: How you think this method is ? I asking for your feedback to understand the solution thinking quality.

Comment: @DEBASHISBAIDYA honestly, it's rather complicated and I'd write something similar to Cardstdani's answer. Still, it was a useful example to learn this subtlety of Python

Comment: @DEBASHISBAIDYA- suggest for next post, try to explain your `logic` or requirements more clear - this way will get answer quicker.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your feedback. Actually I am new and trying to learn without any help. I tried to solve the problem without using any builtin function. Your feedback will help me to understand more.

Comment: Disagreed.  Python is, famously, a "batteries included" language; you have to learn the standard `built-in` and libs to make the best of this language. Right?

Comment: Yeah. But I am focusing more to thinking and algorithmic way, not only the language features. :) 
That's why...

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the list as follows to get the correct output:

```
def solution(A):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        print(A[i:] + A[:i])

inp_arr = [3, 6, 8, 7]
solution(inp_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[6, 8, 7, 3]
[8, 7, 3, 6]
[7, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use the other methods but I need to know what is the problem of this code.