# how to write square grid function in python in for loop

Tags: python

(in Python)
inputs a list and outputs a square grid of values of that list in which each value only appears once in each column and row. each row is the one above it but last item is moved to the front. answer is list of lists,  sub-list is a row of the square

`grid([1, 2, 3, 4]) -> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1]]`

which corresponds to:

1234
4123
3412
2341

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. You are supposed to show how you tried to resolve it by yourself, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

please use this command:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[x[-i:]+x[:-i] for i in range(len(x))]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```