# Why is my function rotating a tuple with length == 1?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I wrote this function to rotate a list to the left and it works fine except when I pass something like a [1,2,3,4], whose length is 1 - so ideally it should return None. How can I edit the code to fix this issue?

```
def rotate_left(list_of_elements):
    if len(list_of_elements) > 1:
        first_element = list_of_elements[0]
        for i in range(len(list_of_elements) - 1):
            list_of_elements[i] = list_of_elements[i+1]
        list_of_elements[-1] = first_element
        return list_of_elements
```

`rotate_left([1,2,3,4],)` gives `[2,3,4,1]`

Comment: `f(x,)` calls f with the value `x`. It is not the same as `f((x,))` which calls it with the tuple `(x,)`.

Comment: If that's of any help, [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html#numpy.roll) can handle this function for you!

Comment: Why are you mentioning tuples when you deal with lists? And why should rotating a list of length 1 return None instead of itself? All this is very unclear to me. Your example does exactly what it's supposed to do, doesn't it?

Comment: Are you open to alternate and simpler implementations? [Efficient way to rotate a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python)

Comment: One clarification, at the moment, `rotate_left([1])` does return `None`, but you seem to want that.  What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: And so does `rotate_left(([1,2,3,4],))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing to do list rotation. `ls[1:]` means all elements from position one to end. `ls[0]` is the first element. To rotate left, put first element to the last. You can use `ls[1:] + [ls[0]]` to join the lists. So the code becomes:

```
def rotate_left(ls):
    if len(ls) >= 2:
        return ls[1:] + [ls[0]]
```

To rotate right, put last element first, use `ls[-1]` to get last element, and `ls[:-1]` to get all elements before the last element.

```
def rotate_right(ls):
    if len(ls) >= 2:
        return [ls[-1]] + ls[:-1]
```

Output:

```
rotate_left([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]

rotate_left([0, 1, 2, 3])
#[1, 2, 3, 0]

rotate_left([0, 1])
#[1, 0]

rotate_right([0, 1])
#[1, 0]

rotate_right([0, 1, 2])
#[2, 0, 1]

rotate_right([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
#[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]

rotate_right([0])
#returns None

rotate_left([])
#returns None
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you were trying to do was pass it a tuple with one list inside, this was answered by @interjay in the comments but, you're not actually passing the function a tuple. For example:

```
list, # not a tuple, just a single list
(list,) # valid tuple with single list inside
```

More examples:

```
list # one list
list, # one list
(list) # also one list
(list,) # tuple with one list inside
(list, list) # tuple with two lists inside
(list, list,) # tuple with two lists inside
```

Also the function is written to accept a single list. If you pass it a tuple, you have to handle for a tuple.

Currently if you pass this function a tuple whose *len* is less than or equal to *1*, it will return *None*; However if the tuple has more than one item inside, it will break:

```
your_function((item,)) # returns None since len is 1
your_function((item, item2)) # breaks program
your_function((item, item2,)) # breaks program
```

#### To fix this add a check to your function:

```
if (type(list_of_elements) != list): return
```

like this:

```
def rotated_left(list_of_elements):
    if (type(list_of_elements) != list): return
    if len(list_of_elements) > 1:
        print(len(list_of_elements))
        first_element = list_of_elements[0]
        for i in range(len(list_of_elements) - 1):
            list_of_elements[i] = list_of_elements[i+1]
        list_of_elements[-1] = first_element
        return list_of_elements
```

#### Things to remember

```
li = [1,2,3] # makes a list
tu = li, # makes a tuple with li
your_function(li,) # passes a list to your function
                   # does not make a tuple and pass it to your function
```

Comment: Actually `x,` *is* a one-element tuple, but you can't use this syntax in a function call because there `,` has a different meaning.