# Why is the output of the print statement outside the method different to the output of final print statement within the method?

Tags: python

Here is my method:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        for i in range(k):
            popped = [nums.pop()]
            nums = popped + nums
            print(nums)
        print(nums)

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
k = 3
Solution().rotate(nums, k)
print(nums)
```

```
# I Expected:

# [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# [6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# I Got:

# [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# [6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Once you do `nums = popped + nums`, the local name `nums` within the function no longer refers to the original list object that you gave to the function. But the global name `nums` continues to refer to that list, so `print(nums)` executed outside the function prints that list.

Answer (score 0):

As per a comment above, `nums = popped + nums` doesn't change (mutate) the existing list, it creates a new list and keeps the old one in memory.  As the external variable still refers to the original list, it doesn't get anything added to it.

That's different from `pop()` which mutates the list without creating a new one, which is why you see the original list without the `7`.

So, you need to mutate the list, not create a new one. Mutation is usually done with `list.some_method()`

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

***In your case; `nums.insert(0, popped)`***

It's an inefficient approach, but it will work. And hopefully help you learn about object references, scope, and mutation.

Comment: Question about efficiently rotating a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python

Comment: `nuns.insert(0, popped)` isn't really any less efficient than constructing `popped + sums`, though.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Just ensuring that I understand properly, during the second iteration of the loop is the new list then mutated but the global list only contains the initial mutation? @MatBailie

Comment: @JamesQuarmby 1). Create list. 2). Call function 3a). Mutate list (pop). 3b). Create new list (popped + nums). 3c). Print new list. 3d). Loop back to 3a using new list instead (mutate it and create yet another list, etc) 4). Leave function, no return value. 5). Print list (having been mutated once, all other operations done on other lists)

Answer (score 0):

The `nums = popped + nums` line generates a new `nums` instance, which is a local variable in the `rotate` method. So, the value of this local variable is changed with each iteration of the for loop. The problem is that in the first iteration, the original array was popped by the `popped =[nums.pop()]` line. That is why you obtain the given value in the final print statement. If you wish to print in the way you specified, you can do so by updating the for loop.

```
for i in range(k):
    popped = nums.pop()
    nums.insert(0, popped)
    print(nums)
```

This will pop the final element of the global `nums` array and place it at the beginning.